# The word order after "or" in a question

Tags: word-order

"Have I already seen you, or that was a dream?"

or

"Have I already seen you, or was that a dream?"  ?

Or does it depend on nuancnes  of meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For the given sentences,* the second one is correct. Because, you have two questions there separated by 'or'.

When we form a question, we put a verb first or else it becomes a sentence.

> Was that a dream? - correct 
>  That was a dream? - incorrect (however, this is also possible but then it is called as a 'declarative question', which is a different case.

So,

> "Have I already seen you, or was that a dream?"

Answer (score 0):

"If I have a question with two options, should I put both in reverse order or I can leave the second one as it is?"

I embedded the problem into the question. It has become quite common in informal usage that the word order is like this:

"Is this just me or it's a general problem?"

"Is this just me or it's down for everyone?"

etc.

According to the grammar rules, it should be

"Is this just me or is it a general problem?"

or

"Is this just me or a general problem?"

But in my opinion all the above are correct.